# Provide a user with service start/stop permissions

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, windows-service

I have a very basic domain that I use for development.  I want to create a GPO that provides users in the Backup Operators group with start/stop permissions for two specific services on a specific server.

I have read several articles about this, and they all indicate that this is very easy.  Create a GPO, give the user start/stop permissions to the services under Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > System Services, and voila.  Done.

Not so much, but I have to be doing something wrong.

My install is pretty much the default.  The domain controller is in the Domain Controllers OU, the Backup Operators group is under Builtin, and I created a user called Backup under Users.

I created a GPO and linked it to the Domain Controllers OU.  In the GPO I give the Backup user permission to start/stop two specific services on the server.  I forced an update with gpupdate.  I used Group Policy Results to verify that my GPO is the winning GPO giving the user the permission to start/stop the two services.

However, the user is still unable to start/stop the services.  I attempted different loopback settings on the GPO to no avail.

I'm sort of at a loss here.

Comment: Is the service you are trying to give them permissions to manage on the domain controller or another server?

Comment: On the domain controller.

Comment: How is the specified user account managing the services?  Is it logged on to the dc console/rdp session as the user?

Comment: I've tried running cmd as the user and logging in via RDP as the user.  Ultimately, however, the point is to run a scheduled task as the user to stop the service, backup its data, and restart the service.

In all cases, I just keep getting an access denied error.

Comment: Let me rephrase that.  I have only tried via RDP.  I have logged in as Administrator to make all of the GPO changes, then tried controlling the services via cmd running as the Backup user.  I have also tried logging in as the Backup user and then attempting to control the services.

Comment: This related question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436558/start-stop-a-windows-service-from-a-non-administrator-user-account

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I've pretty much read all of those linked documents and still run into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity...  I have no idea what I was doing wrong before, but I revisited this and was able to get it to work twice (a second time just to make sure I wasn't crazy) using the exact process I described above with a group policy object.

The only thing I can think of that I might have done differently was giving the Backup user Read privileges as well as Start/Stop/Restart privileges on the services.

Thanks to those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Remote logins require administrator privileges to do any administration on a DC.  GPOs won't help.  And there are no user groups on a domain controller.